# URLSessionDataTask has no member 'map' Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello this is an error I do not know how to fix. from this tutorial:

[Reusable Image Cache in Swift](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/reusable-image-cache-in-swift-9b90eb338e8d)

[image: 5]
Code:

```
final class ImageLoader {

private let cache = ImageCache()

func loadImage(from url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> {
    if let image = cache[url] {
        return Just(image).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
        .map { (data, response) -> UIImage? in return UIImage(data: data) }
        .catch { error in return Just(nil) }
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {[unowned self] image in
            guard let image = image else { return }
            self.cache[url] = image
        })
        .subscribe(on: .background)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
}
```

**Update:**

**If You Use dataTaskPublisher:**
[image]

Comment: Your code is not the same as that link you shared. It used `dataTaskPublisher`. You might need to `import Combine`.

Comment: Yes, I have put a picture of the version where they use dataTaskPublisher at the bottom of the question. As well the error that comes with it. @Rob

Comment: Yes, import Combine is in @Rob

Comment: You have `.subscribe(on: .background)`, and the web site you reference uses `.subscribe(on: backgroundQueue)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `dataTaskPublisher` for that purpose not `dataTask` itself

```
final class ImageLoader {
    
    private let cache = ImageCache()
    
    func loadImage(from url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> {
        if let image = cache[url] {
            return Just(image).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .catch { error in return Just(nil) }
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {[unowned self] image in
                guard let image = image else { return }
                self.cache[url] = image
            })
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```